# If $a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, & $n \mid (a+b)$, prove $n$ does not necessarily divide $ (a^2+b^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

In the exercise 2.4 of Wallace introductory book titled "Groups, Rings and Fields", it is stated that:

> If $a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, & $n \mid (a+b)$, prove $n$ does not necessarily divide $ (a^2+b^2)$.

I am unable to make any progress, as I feel it is only possibly true in complex domain, with $b$ as imaginary part, i.e. $(a+ib)(a-ib) = a^2 + b^2$.

A proof negating the divisibility of $a^2 + b^2$ by such $n$, for $a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is requested.

Comment: Let a=1 and b=2.  3 divides 3, but 3 doesn't divide 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only a single counterexample.

$$a^2 + b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) + 2b^2$$

So, if $n$ divides $a+b$ but not $a^2+b^2$, then it must be that $n$ does not divide $2b^2$.

Any which way you look should produce counterexamples, e.g., $a = 3$, $b = 4$, so that $a+b = 7$ and $a^2 + b^2 = 25$. Pick $n = 7$. Clearly $n$ divides $a+b$ (they are equal) but it does not divide $a^2 + b^2$ since $7$ is not a factor of $25$.

Comment: Is $(a+b)\mid2b^2$. 4 cases can be worked out based on if a,b is odd/ even. If logic is fine, then please vet: (i) If $\exists k,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, & $a=2k,b=2m$, & if $(a+b)\mid2b^2$, then $(k+m) \mid 4m^2$. So, true only when $k\mid m$; (ii) Both $a,b$ odd: $a=2k+1,b=2m+1$, & if $(a+b)\mid 2b^2$, then $2(k+m+1)\mid(4m^2+4m+1)$. So, for odd $a,b$, not possible; (iii) Either $a$,or $b$ is odd: let $a=2k+1, b=2m$, then $(2(k+m)+1)\nmid(4m^2)$, or if $b$ odd, then $(2(k+m)+1)\mid (4m(m+1)+1)$. So, not possible for $a$ being odd, but needs more analysis for $b$ being odd.

Comment: I have stated above comment based on the premise that $n \mid (a+b)$, so need check if $(a+b) \mid 2b^2$,as $n$ is a factor of $(a+b)$.

Answer (score 1):

The hint:

Use $$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$$

and try for example $a=3$, $b=5$ and $n=8$.

Comment: Well $n = 8$ is also perfectly acceptable since neither $4$ nor $8$ divide $3^2 + 5^2 = 34$.... Wait, what happened to the comment?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: @user477343 I realised it, so deleted it.

Comment: @jiten I thought it was glitching hahah